# Save AWS Transcribe JSON Output

Tags: json, amazon-web-services

I'm trying to send an AMS Lambda function to AMS Transcribe to transcribe an audio document. I then want to save this audio document back in the original AMS Lambda function. I know it would likely be easier to instead send it to an S3 Bucket, but that's not part of the brief.

Everything is happening successfully, but I need to be able to access the contents of the transcription for the next step (passing the text into AMS Comprehend). The AMS Transcribe job is created successfully, and when I click to download the transcript, a JSON file downloads with the following contents: -

```
{"jobName":"MY_FILE_NAME","accountId":"MY_ID","results":{"transcripts":[{"transcript":"MY TRANSCRIPT"}],"items":[{"start_time":"0.04","end_time":"0.35","alternatives":[{"confidence":"1.0","content":"better"}],"type":"pronunciation"},{"start_time":"0.35","end_time":"0.71","alternatives":[{"confidence":"1.0","content":"three"}],"type":"pronunciation"},{"start_time":"0.71","end_time":"1.09","alternatives":[{"confidence":"1.0","content":"hours"}],"type":"pronunciation"},{"start_time":"1.09","end_time":"1.29","alternatives":[{"confidence":"1.0","content":"too"}],"type":"pronunciation"},{"start_time":"1.29","end_time":"1.58","alternatives":[{"confidence":"1.0","content":"soon"}],"type":"pronunciation"},{"start_time":"1.58","end_time":"1.73","alternatives":[{"confidence":"0.9991","content":"than"}],"type":"pronunciation"},{"start_time":"1.73","end_time":"1.79","alternatives":[{"confidence":"0.9421","content":"a"}],"type":"pronunciation"},{"start_time":"1.79","end_time":"2.16","alternatives":[{"confidence":"0.9312","content":"minute"}],"type":"pronunciation"},{"start_time":"2.16","end_time":"2.37","alternatives":[{"confidence":"0.925","content":"too"}],"type":"pronunciation"},{"start_time":"2.37","end_time":"2.76","alternatives":[{"confidence":"0.9973","content":"late"}],"type":"pronunciation"},{"alternatives":[{"confidence":"0.0","content":"."}],"type":"punctuation"}]},"status":"COMPLETED"}
```

This file would be great, as I'd be able to get the transcript from the JSON file. However, even when I get the results of my transcription (which are the exact same as the URL to download the JSON file), it doesn't appear that I'm able to read them in JSON format. Here is my code. I've included the process of transcribing, but s3bucket and s3object come from earlier parts of the code.

```
#CREATE TRANSCRIBE JOB
jobName = s3object + '-' + str(uuid.uuid4())

client = boto3.client('transcribe')

response = client.start_transcription_job(
    TranscriptionJobName=jobName,
    LanguageCode='en-US',
    MediaFormat='mp3',
    Media={
        'MediaFileUri': "s3://" + s3bucket + "/" + str(s3object)
    },
)

#TESTING
print(response['TranscriptionJob']['TranscriptionJobName'])
time.sleep(50)
print(response)

# GET TRANSCRIBE FILE
while True:
    result = client.get_transcription_job(TranscriptionJobName=jobName)
    if result['TranscriptionJob']['TranscriptionJobStatus'] in ['COMPLETED', 'FAILED']:
      break
    time.sleep(15)
if result['TranscriptionJob']['TranscriptionJobStatus'] == "COMPLETED":
    data = result['TranscriptionJob']['Transcript']['TranscriptFileUri']
    data = json.loads(data)
    print(data)
```

When I print data, I get the following (which is also the URL to download the file)

```
https://s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/aws-transcribe-eu-west-2-prod/21040557774/MY_FILE_NAME/8127c3b7-dcdf-4f64-8331-e61c7219c942/asrOutput.json?X-Amz-Security-Token=LONG_SECURITY_TOKEN&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Date=20210326T193652Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Expires=900&X-Amz-Credential=MY_CREDENTIAL%2Feu-west-2%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Signature=AMZ_SIGNATURE
```

As this file downloads as a JSON file, I thought I could simply import it to my code via JSON. That's where data = json.loads(data) comes from.

However, when I run this line, I get: -

```
[ERROR] JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 51, in lambda_handler
data = json.loads(data)
```

I know there's the potential to use pandas, but I'm using the AWS CLI and I spent about 2 hours looking at different tutorials, each one offering line for line advice on how to get pandas working, each one breaking halfway through, so if at all avoidable I'd like to open it without having to go beyond a simple import, but if there's no other way then I understand.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use `data = json.loads(data)` since  data is a url and not a formated Json string

try downloading it (for instance with requests library)

```
import requests
data = requests.get(data).json()
```

Comment: Thanks mate. Yeah I saw requests suggested but like pandas, requests isn't one of the libraries available in the AWS CLI and I imagine it's going to take me longer to figure out how to integrate it than solving the original task. Thanks though!

Comment: Just want to say, by explaining to me that the data I was trying to access was a url, a previous workaround to requests did work in the end so you did manage to crack it for me. Appreciate it bud.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Antonin Riche for helping me understand the context of what I was trying to do.

As he explained, I was trying to read in a url, not a json file. As he started, requests() does this, but it isn't a part of the supported imports on AWS Lambda.

```
import urllib3
    
#TESTING
print(response['TranscriptionJob']['TranscriptionJobName'])
time.sleep(50)
print(response)

# GET TRANSCRIBE FILE
while True:
    result = client.get_transcription_job(TranscriptionJobName=jobName)
    if result['TranscriptionJob']['TranscriptionJobStatus'] in ['COMPLETED', 'FAILED']:
      break
    time.sleep(15)
if result['TranscriptionJob']['TranscriptionJobStatus'] == "COMPLETED":
    data = result['TranscriptionJob']['Transcript']['TranscriptFileUri']
    http = urllib3.PoolManager()
    data = http.request('GET', result['TranscriptionJob']['Transcript']['TranscriptFileUri'])
    data = json.loads(data.data.decode('utf-8'))
```

This allows me to read in the http and convert it to JSON like Antonin suggested. I'll then be able to access the JSON file like normal and access my transcript. In this case, that was;

```
print(data['results']['transcripts'][0]['transcript'])
```